# Cluster, Kubernetes, Docker. What to choose for my app?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cluster-computing, container-image

My app is a bash script that runs `tesseract` on `GNU parallel`. The data I need to process is to the tune of 50GB. It's too slow if I do it one VM. I need the power of cluster computing but I don't want to set up multiples VMs myself, instead I just want to launch my APP (along with the data files) on Google cluster (Kubernetes?). I don't have much clarity about these concepts. If someone can guide that would be great.

Comment: See [What kind of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Questions where every answer is equally valid; questions that are-open-ended; and questions that invite sharing experiences are all in the set of things that aren't welcome here, as selecting a "right answer" is subjective rather than objective when there isn't objective criteria to judge them by. Likewise, questions that are extremely broad (and requiring generalized "guidance" is certainly in that set).

Comment: What about single high-end machine? Say, n1-highcpu-96, 96 cpus, ~90Gb of ram, $3.4/h. No changes to the code, single code image, single input data r/o image, output data volume.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux which company is providing that?

Comment: Google, https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing

Answer (score 1):

Might be a challenge to learn all the container orchestration details from scratch when you are just concerned about this one use case.

While GNU Parrellel is nice on a single machine, there don't seem to be many starter kits for using it in distributed mode in the cloud.

I would consider [google dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-cloud-dataflow-for-batch-predictions-with-tensorflow) rather than spining up a K8S cluster.  It allocates and cleans up easily and lets you avoid managing VMs and learning an orchestration framework.

Comment: Parallel has plenty of built-in support for spanning multiple machines; I don't know what kind of "starter kit" you're implying would/should be needed. What it *doesn't* have is orchestration to provision cloud nodes or discover them from a cloud/provider API. (Don't take this comment to be an endorsement of Parallel -- I don't use it myself and don't advise others to either -- but it's more capable than the above implies).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I dont want to get involved in setting up and managing SSH logins of 4-5 VMs (I may need even more), which is what Parallel requires. I think `container` architecture just right for my case but the learning curve seems steep.

Comment: @navicore You understood my pain correctly. I will look into Google dataflow.

Comment: @Naveed, yes, setting up VMs and managing their logins is the "orchestration" layer I spoke of above. If you use that term to search for it, you'll find plenty of tools suited to the job.